# When preparing a general guideline, is "up to that point in time" the right choice to replace "so far"?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, phrase-usage

I prepare a guideline for my colleagues to follow, and I am not sure what is the correct phrase in this context:

> Ask the R&D for feedback about their satisfaction with our cooperation
> up to that/this point in time.

This is a step in the middle of the process, so the cooperation continues. Normally, I would say "so far" but I assume this cannot be used when not referring to a present moment that I am talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd prefer to use *so far* here.

If you say *up to this/that point in time*, you're specific enough to imply that you have a specific cutoff date in mind. Now your colleagues need to work out if you were writing the note from their perspective or yours - does ***this** point in time* refer to "this point in time when I'm writing it" or "this point in time when you're reading/executing the instructions"? Does ***that** point in time refer* to "that point when you'll be reading it" or "that point when I wrote it"?

It's ultimately no less ambiguous, but scares your colleagues into thinking "what if @John V meant feedback up to when he wrote it, and he'll yell at us if we try to gather feedback about further dates"?

On the other hand, *so far* is general enough that your colleagues probably won't think twice about it and just interpret it as "so far" from their perspective as well.

Comment: I see, thanks. I thought I cannot use "so far" because there is no real present moment, it is a general guideline.

Comment: @JohnV *so far* still works well for a general guideline, and probably better than the alternatives. Though ultimately no one's going to keep asking R&D "how was your satisfaction up to \*checks date on guidelines\* March 9"? every single day.